# Storing objects in an Sqlite3 database using C# and WinRT

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

following this guide [here](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/) i have defined a custom class (lets just call it MyClass), and using the sqlite release for WinRT (windows 8/metro apps) and the sqlite-net API obtained from the NuGet package manager within Visual Studio 2012 have been able to create a database file that is meant to store instances of MyClass

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("MyClassDB");
await conn.CreateTableAsync<MyClass>();
```

However MyClass contains arrays (of other custom classes and string arrays) and other "more complex" types than just text and numbers, and even though they are clearly defined in the MyClass definition, they are not being created as accepted fields in the database file (i checked using an sqlite database browser, and by opening the file in notepad, and found just the string and number fields of MyClass)

How do i get the database to store instances of these other types/classes that are present in MyClass, or, assuming that that sort of thing isnt supported, what alternative solution could i use? some of the properties of MyClass will be used for queries etc in the program.

i would be most grateful for any help

Comment: If your objects don't naturally map to relational database tables you are better off using simple serialization and saving it to disk.

Comment: ok, is it possible to serialize a whole object, but also leave it open to queries from the program?